# MongoDB Spark Conflict datatype

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

How to avoid conflict datatypes while mapping Mongodb collections to Spark dataframe. We can't cast conflict datatypes to string. And getting error while performing select operations.

I am using Mongodb-Spark-connector v2.10:1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

The [ConflictType](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/2.x/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/sql/types/ConflictType.scala) indicates that the field was found to contain different data types that cannot be coerced into a unifying type.  In other words, it contains varying types of data. i.e. numbers and strings or strings.
Check your dataframe fields of `ConflictType` by running [printSchema()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations).

In [MongoDB Spark Connector v1](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark), a workaround is to **manually** set the schema for the DataFrame to `string`.

In MongoDB Spark Connector v2, the base type for conflicting types will be in `strings`. see also [SPARK-84](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-84).

Comment: in the case of mongodb spark connector v1 - is there an example of how to do this simply without having to define the whole schema, is there a way of saying 'default schema to string on conflict' feature on the sparkContext?

Answer (score 1):

for those who are working with v1 connector and need to do the manual workaround here is some code i created to fix the issue.

```
 val schema = com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
   .read(sql)
   .option("samplingRatio", "0.3")
   .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
   .option("spark.mongodb.input.database", db)
   .option("spark.mongodb.input.collection", COLLECTION)
   .option("spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name", "secondary")
   .load()

 // replace all instances of conflict with type string from the json
 var schema_json = schema.schema.json.replace("\"type\":\"conflict\"", "\"type\":\"string\"")

 //convert it into a struct object
 val new_schema = DataType.fromJson(schema_json).asInstanceOf[StructType]

 // then load the schema in with the conflict types removed and replaced with string
 val table = com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark.read(sql)
 .schema(new_schema)
 .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri)
 .option("spark.mongodb.input.database", db)
 .option("spark.mongodb.input.collection", COLLECTION)
 .option("spark.mongodb.input.readPreference.name", "secondary")
 .load()
 .repartition(6)
```